# CPU usage of my laptop is awfuly low

Tags: windows, laptop, cpu

When I use hard apps like after effect or extra . I see that my ram usage is 90% and my CPU is 10% or some times 1%

How can I solve this and fix my CPU low usage (Core i5)??

Comment: RAM usage is often rather steady and thus easy to spot. CPU usage is different: Unless you do something like playing a game or converting a video, it will spike momentarily as you perform actions. Did you check the CPU usage over time? Do you feel your computer is not performing well?

Answer (score 2):

The processes are probably not CPU intensive so nothing to fix.

The processes could well be disk intensive, especially if the disk is a 5400-rpm drive. High disk activity could be swapping out to memory to improve disk throughput.

This seems likely here (CPU is low).